# Local get request -> Response Cache - Spring Cloud Gateway - non existent

Tags: spring, caching, cloud, response, gateway

I am trying to make my spring cloud gateway cache reponse bodies for certain get requests in specific path.

I have tried following this [Spring Documentation on LocalResponseCache GatewayFilter Factory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway/gatewayfilter-factories/local-cache-response-filter.html)

However what they state there and what is reality is far apart.

The property called spring.cloud.gateway.filter.local-response-cache.enabled they say I must use does not exist anywhere I can find. and IntelliJ does not list to either.

When I tried adding this filter ( LocalResponseCache=30m,500MB) to my config I get this error:

> Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name LocalResponseCache

Does anyone have any idea? Or an example of a successful implementaton of this?

This is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.13</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>za.co.capitecbank.vas</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>api-gateway</name>
    <description>API Gateway for VAS</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.8</spring-cloud.version>
        <springdoc-openapi.version>1.6.15</springdoc-openapi.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>za.co.capitecbank.strategicprojects.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluent-bit-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc-openapi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.js</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.37.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>
                            <includes>
                                <include>src/main/java/**/*.java</include>
                                <include>src/test/java/**/*.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <trimTrailingWhitespace/>
                            <endWithNewline/>
                            <indent>
                                <spaces>true</spaces>
                                <spacesPerTab>4</spacesPerTab>
                            </indent>
                        </format>
                    </formats>
                    <java>
                        <removeUnusedImports/>
                        <importOrder/>
                        <palantirJavaFormat>
                            <version>2.25.0</version>
                        </palantirJavaFormat>
                    </java>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>apply</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>macos</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
                    <classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

I tried everyting in that doc, nothing matches and when I look into the spring jar, that function localResponseCache does not exist